# ffmpeg sofalizer - Can't find SOFA-file

Tags: ffmpeg, debian

I can't get the **sofalizer** example from *ffmpeg doc* to work.

I always get the same error : **Can't find SOFA-file**

```
ffmpeg -i myAudio5-1.wav -af sofalizer=sofa=/home/santa/Desktop/SOFA/ClubFritz6.sofa:type=freq:radius=1 output.flac
```

(example can be found using `man ffmpeg-all`, then search for `ClubFritz6.sofa`)

Some informations about my system :

```
$ uname -r
4.19.0-16-amd64

$ cat /etc/debian_version
10.9

ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
```

As you can see, I have **libmysofa** enabled.

I tried to change the [wav file as input](https://cdn.lynxstudio.com/go/wp-content/uploads/ChannelPlacement.zip) but the error remains.
I tried to change the [sofa file](http://sofacoustics.org/data/database_sofa_0.6/clubfritz/) but the error remains.

The path of the sofa file is definitely valid. I tried absolute and relative path, but the error remains.

Full error :

```
[Parsed_sofalizer_0 @ 0x560af63ecfc0] Can't find SOFA-file '/home/santa/Desktop/SOFA/ClubFritz6.sofa'
[Parsed_sofalizer_0 @ 0x560af63ecfc0] Error while loading SOFA file: '/home/santa/Desktop/SOFA/ClubFritz6.sofa'
[Parsed_sofalizer_0 @ 0x560af63ecfc0] No valid SOFA file could be loaded. Please specify valid SOFA file.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x560af63ec600] Error initializing filter 'sofalizer' with args 'sofa=/home/santa/Desktop/SOFA/ClubFritz6.sofa:type=freq:radius=1'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Same SOFA file, same command, similar path to file, same ffmpeg version worked for me on Linux.

Comment: @llogan Incredible. Thanks for trying, I'll keep looking for the cause, but it's good to see that it should work!!

Comment: Reinstalled ffmpeg from apt, tried on my Debian laptop (first one was desktop) and exact same error ! Really strange, that I have the same error on both my Debian, desktop and laptop...

Comment: I just tried in a Debian virtual machine (hosted on Windows 10 - Virtual Box), and same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## md5sum

Check sofa file integrity:

```
$ md5sum ClubFritz6.sofa 
68bed61abd2cf3ab6e81a543626162b7  ClubFritz6.sofa
```

## Upgrade libmysofa-dev

Problem is likely old version of [libmysofa](https://github.com/hoene/libmysofa/). Version 1.2 on Arch Linux worked for me. Version 0.6 (libmysofa-dev) on Ubuntu 18.04 did not work.

Comment: Thank you for your investigation! I upgraded from Debian Buster to Debian sid and everything works! So the problem was indeed with libmysofa 0.6!

Answer (score 0):

As
llogan pointed out, the problem was indeed with the libmysofa version.

I will describe the approach that allowed me to solve this problem on Debian 10. It has the merit of making the Debian 10 ffmpeg package work (without having to change the version of ffmpeg).

**1)** Download https://github.com/hoene/libmysofa/releases/tag/v1.2

**2)** Change Version from `/libmysofa-1.2/CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "5")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "1")
```

We will make ldconfig believe that it is the correct version.

**3)** Follow the instructions to compile

**4)** Generate a .deb (still following the instructions)

**5)** Get the lib folder from the .deb (as an archive)

Put this folder somewhere

**6)** `sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/a.conf`

Enter the lib path you have chosen

**7)** `sudo ldconfig`

**8)** `sudo ldconfig -p | less`

You should see something like this

```
libmysofa.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /your-path/lib/libmysofa.so.0
libmysofa.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysofa.so.0
```

The first (new) one will have priority over the old libmysofa which was already installed in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

**9)** `ldd $(which ffmpeg) | less`

To confirm that ffmpeg is using the new library

This method is not very clean, and it might be better to install the latest version of libmysofa from the Debian sid apt source, without upgrading everything. I chose this method for the challenge it presented.